# Injecting beans to library which uses newInstance()

Tags: java, spring, reflection, dependency-injection

Today I want to ask question about spring and `newInstance()` method.

I'm using TyrusProject(generaly websockets in java). I created `EndPoint` bean and `Server` bean. `Server` depends on `endpoint`.

Its constructor looks like this:

```
Server(String path, int port, Class<?> endpoint)
```

And there is problem. `EndPoint` implements `ApplicationContextAware`, to get `applicationContext`. It is set at first, but then server creates it's own instance of endpoint and I get `NullPointerException`.

Is there any way I can do something about it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [my writeup here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19896871/1189885). My general advice would be to look at `@Configurable` if you're stuck with Tyrus and to see whether the Spring WebSocket support with Spring Boot might not be an easier approach.

Comment: Propably it'd be better to use Spring WebSocket. Thanks a lot.